# Pandas dataframe: Frequency plot with hue based on different columns that share same string entries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I'm analysing this Kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/astronasko/transport-for-london-journey-information

I've created a DataFrame with all the completed journeys, where the start station ('StartStn') and end station ('EndStn') are not the same and there is information on each of them.

I've created a frequency plot of Start stations and a separate frequency plot of end stations (see images below):

[image]

[image]

Figure 1 code:
`complete['StartStn'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='bar')`

Figure 2 code:
`complete['EndStn'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='bar')`

Here is a sample of the dataframe, taking a subset of just these two columns:

**IN:**

```
complete[['StartStn','EndStn']].sample(10)
```

**OUT:**

```
        StartStn             EndStn
102417  Leytonstone          East Ham
995246  Walthamstow Central  Piccadilly Circus
1102327 Earls Court          Holborn
604323  Stratford            Shepherd's Bush Und
481718  Warren Street        Walthamstow Central
2344106 Marble Arch          Northolt
1234444 Colliers Wood        Holborn
1408620 Earls Court          Marble Arch
465436  Tottenham Court Rd   Mile End
1580309 Woodside Park        Hammersmith D
```

As you can see, many stations, such as 'Walthamstow Central', are in both columns.

**Problem:**

*Using seaborn, matplotlib or pandas, how do I create a frequency plot for all stations that has a hue of StartStn vs EndStn (i.e. on the same axes)?*

The best I can do is to create a frequency plot with all stations, combining frequencies in 'StartStn' and 'EndStn':

```
stations = pd.concat([complete['StartStn'],complete['EndStn']],axis=0)
stations.value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='bar')
```

Which gives me the following output:
*Most Popular Stations (Start or End)*
[image]

Would be very grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks a lot,

Beni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy Certiprince
You can use countplot from seaborn and utilize Startstn and Endstn as a "hue" so that there are 2 bars per station.
Please find below a suitable code. I have tried with your sample with 10 items.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from collections import OrderedDict

columns = ['StartStn','EndStn']
startstn = ['Leytonstone','Walthamstow','Earls Court','Stratford','Warren Street','Marble Arch','Colliers Wood',
            'Earls Court','Tottenham Court Rd','Woodside Park']
endstn = ['East Ham','Piccadilly Circus','Holborn','Shepherds Bush Und','Walthamstow Central','Northolt',
          'Holborn','Marble Arch','Mile End','Hammersmith D']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'StartStn':startstn,'EndStn':endstn})
print(df)

df['hue'] = 'Start'
df['Stations'] = df['StartStn']
df_start = df[['Stations','hue']]
df['hue'] = 'End'
df['Stations'] = df['EndStn']
df_end = df[['Stations','hue']]

orderstart = df['StartStn'].value_counts()
startstnlist = orderstart.index.tolist()
orderend = df['EndStn'].value_counts()
endstnlist = orderend.index.tolist()
order = startstnlist+endstnlist
order = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(order))

df_concatenated = pd.concat([df_start,df_end],ignore_index=True)
sns.countplot(data=df_concatenated,x='Stations', order=order,hue='hue')
plt.show()
```

Edit:
I have included a piece of code so that the diagram is ordered and the order is given by the startstation frequency